# What is a Scoped Repository Key?

Tags: topology-manager

In the Topology Manager, the following entities have a property called `ScopedRepositoryKeys` (in each case a collection of String):

- Website
- WebApplication
- CdTopology
- CdEnvironment

As far as I can tell, the only use to which this property is put is the configuration of Site Types to support the Site Wizard, so obviously the first question is why isn't the property called `SiteWizardKeys` or something similar? (Yes - I understand this is one of [the two hard things](https://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/506010907021828096?lang=en), so I'm not getting on anyone's case or anything!)

I suppose the less explicit name leaves the possibility of putting this mechanism to other uses in the future, but I'd still like to know why it's called what it is.

- Scoped: In what sense is it scoped? What sort of scopes are we talking about here?
- Repository: OK - I can guess this one. Repository just means publication, right? (Until some other kind of repository comes along, of course.)
- Keys: After a bit of digging, I realised that this refers to the 'key' refers to the `key` property of a publication.

So `Scoped` remains the interesting part. Are we talking about a scope that encompasses a publication, a topology, an environment, a web site and an application?

How should I interpret this in a way that promotes understanding of the mechanisms involved?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A Publication (or, more generically, a *Repository*) can act as a *Site Type* by setting its Publication Type to “Site Type” and setting its Key to some symbolic name.

When creating a new Site using the Site Wizard, the user has to choose a Site Type. The Site Wizard will create a new Publication for the Site and that Publication will be a child Publication of the Repository acting as Site Type.

To keep the Site Wizard simple (i.e. to avoid many additional decisions for the User), the Site Type implicitly also provides mappings to Web Application(s) in Topology Manager. It can do this because the Web Applications are scoped to the Repository acting as Site Type (through its Key). Henced the term “Scoped Repository Key”.

Admittedly, it is a bad (way too technical) name. `SiteTypeKey` would have been much better. This was realized during development, but too late. Note that the cmdlet used to set these “Scoped Repository Keys” is called... guess what... `Set-TtmSiteTypeKey`.

Comment: Thanks Rick. Just the kind of background I was looking for.. In other words, SiteTypeKey is a better name for ScopedRepositoryKey, and not an entirely different concept. When this is not explicit, you can spend a lot of energy wondering if you are interpreting it correctly.